# How to move a a certain percentage of all the files in a directory into another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have like the following datastructure:

```
-folder1
--subfolder1
--subfolder2
--ytz
--subfolder128
-folder2
--subfolder1
--subfolder2
--ytz
--subfolder128
```

in each of these subfolders of folder1 there are different number of files. I want 10% of these files moved to corresponding subfolder of folder2 and have them delete in the corresponding folder of folder1.

All of the subfolders (from folder1/folder2) are named the same.

I know how to move files from one directory to another

```
for i in range(len(synonym_list)):
    dest1 = '../data/mushrooms_with_seperates_synonms/'+synonym_list[i][0]+'/'
    for j in range(len(synonym_list[i])):
        if (j != 0):
            source = '../data/mushrooms_with_seperates_synonms/'+synonym_list[i][j]+'/'
            files = os.listdir(source)
            for f in files:
                    shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
            shutil.rmtree(source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(synonym_list)):
    dest1 = '../data/mushrooms_with_seperates_synonms/'+synonym_list[i][0]+'/'
    for j in range(len(synonym_list[i])):
        if (j != 0):
            source = '../data/mushrooms_with_seperates_synonms/'+synonym_list[i][j]+'/'
            files = os.listdir(source)
            for k, f in enumerate(files):
                if not k % 10:
                    shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why ```if not k % 10``` yields 10% of the files?

Comment: Because it's true on every tenth iteration through the loop, thus 10% of the files are moved.

Comment: Brilliant. What if I'm trying to do a 70% / 15% / 15% split? It looks like ```if not k % 5``` would work for 20%...